# How to use mailparser php

Tags: php

I ma trying to show in browser the email header of email /home/mail/02092290663929254284:2,S , using php and mailpaser. I am using this code

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('/usr/local/MimeMailParser.class.php');
$path = '/home/mail/02092290663929254284:2,S';
$Parser = new MimeMailParser();
$Parser->setPath($path);

$to = $Parser->getHeader('to');
$delivered_to = $Parser->getHeader('delivered_to');
$from = $Parser->getHeader('from');
$subject = $Parser->getHeader('subject');
$text = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
$html = $Parser->getMessageBody('html');
$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();
$headers=$Parser->getHeadersRaw('headers');

echo $Parser->getHeadersRaw(); # print email header

foreach($headers as $headersvalue){
    echo "$headersvalue<br>";
}

?>
```

but I am receiving the error
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/local/test.php

Why ? How to solve it ?

Thank you

Comment: `$Parser->getHeadersRaw();` is not an array. And also, you are using `$Parser->getHeadersRaw('headers');`. What will output this: `var_dump($Parser->getHeadersRaw('headers'));`?

Comment: var_dump($Parser->getHeadersRaw('headers'));
works ok , thank you , however the output is now showing well in a browser , I need to <br> each row , how to do that please ?

Comment: Because its not an `array`, but simple `string`. Thats why you cant use `foreach`. And also I dont understand, why you accepted wrong answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('/usr/local/MimeMailParser.class.php');
$path = '/home/mail/02092290663929254284:2,S';
$Parser = new MimeMailParser();
$Parser->setPath($path);

$to = "to@to.com" //Reciver email address
$form   =   "sender@sender.com" // Sender email address
$subject    =   "Email Subject"; //Email Subject
$emailBody  =   "Email Message"; // Your email message

$to = $Parser->getHeader($to);
$delivered_to = $Parser->getHeader('delivered_to');
$from = $Parser->getHeader($form);
$subject = $Parser->getHeader($subject);
$text = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
$html = $Parser->getMessageBody($emailBody);
$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();
$headers=$Parser->getHeadersRaw('headers');

echo $Parser->getHeadersRaw(); # print email header

foreach($headers as $headersvalue){
    echo "$headersvalue<br>";
}

?>
```

Try now.

> $to is Reciver email address
>   $form is Sender email address
>   $subject is Email Subject
>   $emailBody is  Your email message

Comment: `$Parser->getHeadersRaw('headers')` is not an array, it will throw the same error...

Answer (score 1):

`$Parser->getHeadersRaw();` is not an array. And also, you are using `$Parser->getHeadersRaw('headers');`. What will output this: `var_dump($Parser->getHeadersRaw('headers'));`?

Here is an example usage:

```
<?php

require_once('MimeMailParser.class.php');

$path = 'path/to/mail.txt';
$Parser = new MimeMailParser();
$Parser->setPath($path);

$to = $Parser->getHeader('to');
$from = $Parser->getHeader('from');
$subject = $Parser->getHeader('subject');
$text = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
$html = $Parser->getMessageBody('html');
$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();

?>
```